# Looking for a tool to step STM32 core and log registers with st-link

Tags: debugging, stm32, st-link

I'm currently reverse engineering a device I have in hand that uses STM32F030 mcu.

**I'm in need of a software tool** that will reset the core, continuously step the core and will log the registers at each step for a predefined amount of steps or time.

It will help me understand how to initialize and communicate with a peripheral that is on the device.

I'm able to manually step the core(manually advance the program by 1 clock) and see the registers, GPIO output registers to be exact. I do this through STM32CubeProgrammer with a clone st-link v2, I also have genuine st-link v2.

A quick search revealed nothing and to be honest I don't know what will I search this as. Being able to manually do this I believe there would be a tool that does this automatically.

I know another solution is to use a logic analyzer and record it but it both requires the analyzer, which I don't have, and soldering wires everywhere.

Any help or direction is appreciated!

Comment: Write the gdb script

Comment: But it will not help you in most cases as you will not know what is happening in the interrupts. Also if program uses RTOS then this method will get you to nowhere